# Omitting the Milliseconds in a Date

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2005, t-sql

When I select from SQL Server, I want to get a date, but omit the millisecond value, and I want it to be as a date type.  So if I have a value `1/1/2009 1:23:11.923`, I want to omit the millisecond but retain the date type, so that it will be the value `1/1/2009 1:23:11.000` (I know you really can't omit the millisecond value with a date, just want it to be zero).

Is there a function in SQL Server to do this?  Or do I have to write my own function?  Again, I don't want it as a `varchar` type, but a `datetime` type.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you don't want to use string conversions, here's a solution:

```
DECLARE @TheDate datetime, @Today datetime
SET @TheDate = GetDate()

SET @Today = DateAdd(dd, DateDiff(dd, 0, @TheDate), 0)
SELECT DateAdd(s, DateDiff(s, @Today, @TheDate), @Today)
```

Comment: This works perfectly without rounding to the seconds. Helped me. Thanks :)

Comment: For those who are looking for answer without milliseconds part then this is not for you, This give '000' at milliseconds, You can try @Peter Radocchia's approach. If you are okay with '000' this is perfect for you. 
But cleaner the better

Answer (score 58):

Use `DATETIME2`, a new datatype in SQL Server 2008 that supports fractional precision:

```
SELECT
  CONVERT(DATETIME2(0),SYSDATETIME()) [yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss]
, CONVERT(DATETIME2(1),SYSDATETIME()) [yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.f]
, CONVERT(DATETIME2(2),SYSDATETIME()) [yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.ff]
, CONVERT(DATETIME2(3),SYSDATETIME()) [yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.fff]
, CONVERT(DATETIME2(4),SYSDATETIME()) [yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.ffff]
, CONVERT(DATETIME2(5),SYSDATETIME()) [yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.fffff]
, CONVERT(DATETIME2(6),SYSDATETIME()) [yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.ffffff]
, CONVERT(DATETIME2(7),SYSDATETIME()) [yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.fffffff]
```

The conversion will round to the nearest unit, eg:

```
2014-09-04 09:35:47.0162993 as DATETIME2(4) -> 
2014-09-04 09:35:47.0163
```

Alternatively, on SQL 2005 and eariler:

```
SELECT
  original  = GETDATE()
, [floor]   = DATEADD(ms,-DATEPART(ms,GETDATE()),GETDATE())
, [ceiling] = DATEADD(ms,1000-DATEPART(ms,GETDATE()),GETDATE())
, [rounded] = DATEADD(ms,CASE WHEN DATEPART(ms,GETDATE()) < 500 THEN 0 ELSE 1000 END-DATEPART(ms,GETDATE()),GETDATE())
```

This is a bit faster than converting to and from a string representation.

Comment: Wow, that's great, but unfortunately, SQL Server 2005 :-(

Comment: Brian, I removed the SQL Server 2008 tag.  If you need a solution that only works on 2005, you shouldn't tag with a version that is not correct.

Comment: Note that this excellent solution rounds, rather than truncates, at least for DATETIME2(0).  I did not test them all.

Comment: @PeterRadocchia I have not checked the SQL 2005 statements, but the ones that use DATETIME2 round the milliseconds to the nearest second.

Comment: @RashmiPandit, is that good or bad, or just something I should note in the answer?

Comment: @PeterRadocchia you should mention it. People may use your solution depending on whether they need rounding or plain truncation

Comment: @RashmiPandit, I have edited my answer to note the rounding behavior, and I have also replaced GETDATE() w/ SYSDATETIME() to better illustrate the effect.

Comment: Tried various options event marked as answer answers didn't worked for me from various posts, this one is excellent

Answer (score 14):

Use:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), GETDATE(), 120))
```

This:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), GETDATE(), 120)
```

...omits the milliseconds, returning a VARCHAR.  So you CAST/CONVERT that into a DATETIME in order to work with the desired data type.

See [this link for a list of various date/time formats you can work with](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx).

Comment: Converting number to string, and then back again is highly inefficient. Use the datetime functions provided within SQL

Answer (score 6):

try this

```
 declare @DATE datetime
 select @DATE = '1/1/2009 1:23:11.923'



 SELECT convert(datetime,CONVERT(char(35),@DATE,120))
```

or with date functions only

```
DECLARE @DATE DATETIME
SELECT @DATE = '1/1/2009 1:23:11.923'

SELECT DATEADD(SECOND, DATEDIFF(SECOND, 39000, @DATE), 39000)
```

Comment: Converting number to string, and then back again is highly inefficient. Use the datetime functions provided within SQL

Comment: you will get an overflow with with milliseconds

Comment: All you have to do is subtract the milliseconds w/ DATEADD(). No adding from 0 required.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT  GETDATE(),
        CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), GETDATE(), 120), 120)
```

Comment: Isn't the `, 120` on the outermost CONVERT redundant?

Comment: the CONVERT format style (120) is ignored when converting from string to datetime.  BOL says: _the style of the date format used to convert datetime or smalldatetime data to character data (nchar, nvarchar, char, varchar, nchar, or nvarchar data types); or the string format used to convert float, real, money, or smallmoney data to character data (nchar, nvarchar, char, varchar, nchar, or nvarchar data types). When style is NULL, the result returned is also NULL._

Comment: @KM: in this very case, the argument is redundant indeed since this very format leaves no chance for ambiguity. However, it's not always the case. Just run this: `SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '01/02/2010', 101), CONVERT(DATETIME, '01/02/2010', 103)`.

Comment: @KM: I think you have a very outdated version of Books Online (possibly 2000 or 2005 RTM)?  There have been several updates since then, you should make sure your local copy is up to date.  Observe the changed wording in the CAST and CONVERT topic:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928%28SQL.90%29.aspx - @Quassnoi is absolutely correct, in fact I was going to post the exact same example he did.

Comment: @Quassnoi: VARCHAR(MAX) might be a little much, no?  :-)

Comment: Converting number to string, and then back again is highly inefficient. Use the datetime functions provided within SQL

Answer (score 3):

Subtract millisecond from date. (Or add negative value of millisecond)

```
SELECT DATEADD(ms, -DATEPART(ms, GETDATE()), GETDATE())
```

From [SQL Server remove milliseconds from datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286849/sql-server-remove-milliseconds-from-datetime)

Answer (score 2):

```
DATEADD(SECOND, DATEDIFF(SECOND, 0, < your datetime column >), 0)
```

May need to change the 0 to something else to prevent an overflow error. Don't have a SQL Server at hand right now to verify.

While this method does not appear to be intuitive at first sight, have a look here for the rationale behind it: http://karaszi.com/the-ultimate-guide-to-the-datetime-datatypes

Comment: Lol. Good catch, Aaron. Changed it.