# SQL Server remove milliseconds from datetime

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
select *
from table
where date > '2010-07-20 03:21:52'
```

which I would expect to not give me any results... EXCEPT I'm getting a record with a datetime of `2010-07-20 03:21:52.577`

how can I make the query ignore milliseconds?

Comment: If you post (SQL) code or XML, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code" button (101 010) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 114, accepted):

You just have to figure out the millisecond part of the date and subtract it out before comparison, like this:

```
select * 
from table 
where DATEADD(ms, -DATEPART(ms, date), date) > '2010-07-20 03:21:52'
```

Comment: Please mind that this literally removes milliseconds, it does not remove the smaller units, e.g. For `'2021-06-14 00:00:00.1234567'`  `select DATEADD(ms, -DATEPART(ms, date), date)` produces `2021-06-14 00:00:00.0004567`

Answer (score 49):

If you are using SQL Server (starting with 2008), choose one of this:

- CONVERT(DATETIME2(0), YourDateField)
- LEFT(RTRIM(CONVERT(DATETIMEOFFSET, YourDateField)), 19)
- CONVERT(DATETIMEOFFSET(0), YourDateField) *-- with the addition of a time zone offset*

Comment: The DATETIME2 option rounds up if > 0.5, the LEFT(RTRIM option truncates. Both are useful

Answer (score 21):

Try:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE datetime > 
CONVERT(DATETIME, 
CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), 
CONVERT(DATETIME, '2010-07-20 03:21:52'), 120))
```

Or if your date is an actual datetime value:

```
DECLARE @date DATETIME
SET @date = GETDATE()
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), @date, 120))
```

The conversion to style 120 cuts off the milliseconds...

Comment: `CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), @date, 120))` is a great solution for comparing DateTime values while ignoring milliseconds. Thanks.

Comment: VARCHAR(20) was throwing a conversion error for me but I found using VARCHAR(19) instead did the trick

Answer (score 19):

```
select * from table
     where DATEADD(ms, DATEDIFF(ms, '20000101', date), '20000101') > '2010-07-20 03:21:52'
```

You'll have to trim milliseconds before comparison, which will be slow over many rows

Do one of these to fix this:

- created a computed column with the expressions above to compare against
- remove milliseconds on insert/update to avoid the read overhead
- If SQL Server 2008, use [`datetime2(0)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335.aspx)

Comment: datetime2 is the best (least expensive) solution IMO

Comment: @vacip: in 2010 there would have been less SQL Server 2008+ and more SQL Server 2005 which did not have datetime2

Comment: In my experience datetime2(0) will round up the "2020-07-01 15:16:39.837" to "2020-07-01 15:16:40", so is not the best option.

Comment: Please note that casting to `datetime2(0)` will round, not trim.

Answer (score 13):

Use *CAST* with following parameters:

**Date**

```
select Cast('2017-10-11 14:38:50.540' as date)
```

Output: 2017-10-11

**Datetime**

```
select Cast('2017-10-11 14:38:50.540' as datetime)
```

Output: 2017-10-11 14:38:50.540

**SmallDatetime**

```
select Cast('2017-10-11 14:38:50.540' as smalldatetime)
```

Output: 2017-10-11 14:39:00

*Note this method rounds to whole minutes (so you lose the seconds as well as the milliseconds)*

**DatetimeOffset**

```
select Cast('2017-10-11 14:38:50.540' as datetimeoffset)
```

Output: 2017-10-11 14:38:50.5400000 +00:00

**Datetime2**

```
select Cast('2017-10-11 14:38:50.540' as datetime2)
```

Output: 2017-10-11 14:38:50.5400000

Answer (score 10):

For this particular query, why make expensive function calls for each row when you could just ask for values starting at the next higher second:

```
select *
from table
where date >= '2010-07-20 03:21:53'
```

Comment: It is very likely that the date value is not entered manually, but comes from some variable containing the date, which will be inserted in the query. 
Therefore, you would need to use functions anyway, as it would be necessary to add 1 second to the time used in the WHERE clause, using for example the function DATEADD(second, 1, date). ;)

Answer (score 4):

Use 'Smalldatetime' data type

```
select convert(smalldatetime, getdate())
```

will fetch

```
2015-01-08 15:27:00
```

Comment: this truncates also seconds which is not what asker wants.

Comment: Thank you. Nice and clean way

Answer (score 1):

There's more than one way to do it:

```
select 1 where datediff(second, '2010-07-20 03:21:52', '2010-07-20 03:21:52.577') >= 0
```

or

```
select *
from table
where datediff(second, '2010-07-20 03:21:52', date) >= 0
```

one less function call, but you have to be beware of overflowing the max integer if the dates are too far apart.

Answer (score 0):

One more way I've set up SQL Server queries to ignore milliseconds when I'm looking for events from a particular second (in a parameter in "YYYY-MM-DD HH:TT:SS" format) using a stored procedure:

```
  WHERE 
  ...[Time_stamp] >= CAST(CONCAT(@YYYYMMDDHHTTSS,'.000') as DateTime) AND 
  ...[Time_stamp] <= CAST(CONCAT(@YYYYMMDDHHTTSS,'.999') as DateTime)
```

You could use something similar to ignore minutes and seconds too.

Answer (score 0):

**Please try this**

```
select substring('12:20:19.8470000',1,(CHARINDEX('.','12:20:19.8470000',1)-1))


(No column name)
12:20:19
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm very late but I had the same issue a few days ago. None of the solutions above worked or seemed fit. I just needed a timestamp without milliseconds so I converted to a string using Date_Format and then back to a date with Str_To_Date:

```
STR_TO_DATE(DATE_FORMAT(your-timestamp-here, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'),'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')
```

Its a little messy but works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

select CONVERT(datetime, FORMAT(yourdate, 'M/d/yyyy h:m:s'))

Answer (score -1):

May be this will help..
SELECT [Datetime] = CAST('20120228' AS smalldatetime)

o/p:
2012-02-28 00:00:00

Answer (score -1):

Review this example:

```
declare @now datetimeoffset = sysdatetimeoffset();
select @now;
-- 1
select convert(datetimeoffset(0), @now, 120);
-- 2
select convert(datetimeoffset, convert(varchar, @now, 120));
```

which yields output like the following:

```
2021-07-30 09:21:37.7000000 +00:00
-- 1
2021-07-30 09:21:38 +00:00
-- 2
2021-07-30 09:21:37.0000000 +00:00
```

Note that for (1), the result is *rounded* (up in this case), while for (2) it is *truncated*.

Therefore, if you want to **truncate** the milliseconds off a date(time)-type value as per the question, you **must** use:

```
declare @myDateTimeValue = <date-time-value>
select cast(convert(varchar, @myDateValue, 120) as <same-type-as-@myDateTimeValue>);
```