# SQL Server 2005 error retrieving record based on Datetime primary key column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, datetime, composite-primary-key

I have a table in SQL Server 2005 with composite primary key, i.e. a foreign key (INT) and DateTime column.

When i run the SQL,

```
Select column1 From TABLE where ForeignKey=1 and DateTime='08/26/2010 11:24:36'
```

No record was return when there is such a record.

One option to do is

```
Select column1 From TABLE where ForeignKey=1 and DateTime>='08/26/2010 11:24:36' and DateTime<'08/26/2010 11:24:37'
```

But then, it just seems... 
Do i really have to resort to this? or it is because i have to specify until millisecond?
Or is there any solutions?

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Very similar question and answer can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286849/

Comment: 10x 8kb.. That's a similar question which i didn't managed to find.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you would have to match the precision of the DateTime value to the millisecond for the equality to work.

Your proposed alternative will work. As another idea, you could use a [cast and convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) to truncate your stored datetime down to the second. Note however that using these functions in the where clause will negate the optimizer's ability to use any index on your datetime column. You'll have to decide what impact that would have in your specific environment.

```
/* CONVERT style 20 is yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss */
Select column1 
    From TABLE 
    where ForeignKey=1 
        and CAST(CONVERT(char(19),DateTime,20) as datetime) = '08/26/2010 11:24:36'
```

**EDIT**: Following up on the comments below, I've noticed that SQL Server does not seem to pick up a 1 millisecond difference in a comparison. This is true in 2000/2005/2008 environments. If I use the new [datetime2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335.aspx) datatype in 2008, then it works as expected. Reading up on the [datetime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx) datatype, the accuracy of the millisecond portion is rounded:

> Accuracy: Rounded to increments of
>   .000, .003, or .007 seconds

```
declare @datetime1 datetime
declare @datetime2 datetime
declare @datetime3 datetime
declare @datetime4 datetime

set @datetime1 = '2010-08-30 08:41:51.513'
set @datetime2 = '2010-08-30 08:41:51.513'
set @datetime3 = '2010-08-30 08:41:51.514'
set @datetime4 = '2010-08-30 08:41:51.515'

/* Expected result 'Equal'; Actual result 'Equal' */
if @datetime1 = @datetime2
    print 'Equal'
else
    print 'Not Equal'

/* Expected result 'Not Equal'; Actual result 'Equal' */    
if @datetime1 = @datetime3
    print 'Equal'
else
    print 'Not Equal'

/* Expected result 'Not Equal'; Actual result 'Not Equal' */    
if @datetime1 = @datetime4
    print 'Equal'
else
    print 'Not Equal'
```

Comment: Is there a way to compare until the millisecond in SQL Server 2005??? 

Currently I have changed the structure of the table to add a Identity Primary Key column instead of using the ForeignKey with DateTime composite-primary-key. This seems to be recommended.

Comment: Interestingly, there seems to be some loss of precision at the millisecond level. I've appended some sample code to my answer. A difference of 1 millisecond is not picked up, but a difference of 2 milliseconds is. I've gotten the same results on 2K/2005/2008.

Answer (score 0):

If at all possible don't use a datetime field as your key. Instead create a different key and simply index your datetime value.