# order by multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I need to order data by two columns, How do i do that?

This is my table:

```
Name   |  ImpFile   |  ImpTime
Sam      Imp01        2012-05-16 09:54:02.477
Ann      Imp01        2012-05-16 09:54:02.478
Mark     Imp01        2012-05-16 09:54:02.477
John     Import12     2012-05-16 09:55:37.384
Bart     Import12     2012-05-16 09:55:37.387
Sasha    Import12     2012-05-16 09:55:37.385
```

I need to sort this table by ImpTime and ImpName and it should look like this:

```
Name   |  ImpFile   |  ImpTime
         Import12    2012-05-16 09:55:37.387
Bart     Import12    2012-05-16 09:55:37.387
John     Import12    2012-05-16 09:55:37.384
Sasha    Import12    2012-05-16 09:55:37.385
         Imp01       2012-05-16 09:54:02.478
Ann      Imp01       2012-05-16 09:54:02.478
Mark     Imp01       2012-05-16 09:54:02.477
Sam      Imp01       2012-05-16 09:54:02.477
```

I am using this query, but it does not order the table by Name, in only orders by name when the time is the same value for multiple rows.

```
select Name, ImpFile, ImpTime
from people
union
select distinct '', ImpFile, max(ImpTime)
from people 
group by ImpFile
order by ImpTime desc, Name
```

This query gives me table like this:

```
Name   |  ImpFile   |  ImpTime
         Import12     2012-05-16 09:55:37.387
John     Import12     2012-05-16 09:55:37.384
Bart     Import12     2012-05-16 09:55:37.387
Sasha    Import12     2012-05-16 09:55:37.385
         Imp01        2012-05-16 09:54:02.478
Sam      Imp01        2012-05-16 09:54:02.477
Ann      Imp01        2012-05-16 09:54:02.478
Mark     Imp01        2012-05-16 09:54:02.477
```

Is there any way to order by those two column at the same time?

**EDIT**
What happens when I use `order by ImpFile DESC, ImpTime desc`?
It gives me a result table like this:

```
Name   |  ImpFile   |  ImpTime
         Import12    2012-05-16 09:55:37.387
         Imp01       2012-05-16 09:54:02.478
Bart     Import12    2012-05-16 09:55:37.387
John     Import12    2012-05-16 09:55:37.384
Sasha    Import12    2012-05-16 09:55:37.385
Ann      Imp01       2012-05-16 09:54:02.478
Mark     Imp01       2012-05-16 09:54:02.477
Sam      Imp01       2012-05-16 09:54:02.477
```

Comment: _"Is there any way to order by those two column at the same time?"_ You're already ordering by two columns at the same time, so what is your question? The time has priority since it's the first column you want to order by. The `Name` will only be taken into account on records with the same `ImpTime`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Is there a way to set the priority to both columns the same?

Comment: @Kshitij to add a row only with impfile and date without name

Comment: Hi Brezhnews, isn't my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10615674) my correct? Please have a look, based on your requirement, the milliseconds is not important

Comment: Based on your desired output, no matter how I look at it, the milliseconds is disregarded on sorting. If this is the case, my answer is correct. Unless you can give another data sample with the desired output that would prove otherwise ツ

Comment: If you sort by descending ImpTime with the milliseconds intact, on your desired output, how come John(2012-05-16 09:55:37. **384**) comes before Sasha(2012-05-16 09:55:37. **385**) ?

Comment: `datetime`'s granularity is roughly 3 ms (more precise, it's 10/3 ms, I guess). When stored as `datetime`, `2012-05-16 09:55:37.385` turns into `2012-05-16 09:55:37.384`.

Comment: When you use `datetime2`, your query in your question is already correct ツ All our answers here are a moot point ;-)

Comment: "*When **stored** as datetime, 2012-05-16 09:55:37.385 turns into 2012-05-16 09:55:37.384*"  Hmm.. why you didn't include this peculiarity in your question, if both of them get stored in 384, how on earth can stackoverfellows knows we are formulating a query on correct data? Your query is already correct if data consistency(385 gets stored as 385, and 384 gets stored as 384; yet you didn't mention quickly there's data peculiarity; 385 precision is lost with datetime, so it gets stored really as 384) was maintained

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get the leader of each group and sort them by descending time:

```
with grp(Name,ImpFile,TimeGroup,ImpTime) as 
(
  select cast(null as varchar(5)), ImpFile, max(ImpTime) as TimeGroup, 
         max(ImpTime) as ImpTime
  from people 
  group by ImpFile  
)
select * 
from grp
order by TimeGroup desc;
```

Output:

```
NAME      IMPFILE   TIMEGROUP                     IMPTIME
(null)    Import12  2012-05-16 09:55:37.3870000   2012-05-16 09:55:37.3870000
(null)    Imp01     2012-05-16 09:54:02.4780000   2012-05-16 09:54:02.4780000
```

Then join the followers to leader and get the leader's time(TimeGroup):

```
with grp(Name,ImpFile,TimeGroup,ImpTime) as 
(
  select cast(null as varchar(5)), ImpFile, max(ImpTime) as TimeGroup, 
         max(ImpTime) as ImpTime
  from people 
  group by ImpFile  

  union all

  select p.Name, p.ImpFile, ldr.TimeGroup, p.ImpTime
  from people p
  inner join grp ldr -- leader
  on ldr.name is null and ldr.ImpFile = p.ImpFile
)
select Name, ImpFile, ImpTime
from grp 
order by TimeGroup desc, Name
```

Output:

```
NAME      IMPFILE   IMPTIME
(null)    Import12  2012-05-16 09:55:37.3870000
Bart      Import12  2012-05-16 09:55:37.3870000
John      Import12  2012-05-16 09:55:37.3840000
Sasha     Import12  2012-05-16 09:55:37.3850000
(null)    Imp01     2012-05-16 09:54:02.4780000
Ann       Imp01     2012-05-16 09:54:02.4780000
Mark      Imp01     2012-05-16 09:54:02.4770000
Sam       Imp01     2012-05-16 09:54:02.4770000
```

The logic of the query is, we align the followers(those with name)'s time to their leader's time(TimeGroup) based on ImpFile. Leader and its followers have same time group, so when we sort them by time, they will stick to each other; then after that, we sort by name

Live test: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c7859/21

---

If we want the group leader to appear after its followers, just put a case when on ORDER BY:

```
with grp(Name,ImpFile,TimeGroup,ImpTime) as 
(
  select cast(null as varchar(5)), ImpFile, max(ImpTime) as TimeGroup, 
         max(ImpTime) as ImpTime
  from people 
  group by ImpFile  

  union all

  select p.Name, p.ImpFile, ldr.TimeGroup, p.ImpTime
  from people p
  inner join grp ldr -- leader
  on ldr.name is null and ldr.ImpFile = p.ImpFile
)
select Name, ImpFile, ImpTime
from grp 
order by TimeGroup desc, 

  case 
  when Name is null then 2 -- leader last
  else 1 -- followers first
  end,

  Name
```

Output:

```
NAME      IMPFILE   IMPTIME
Bart      Import12  2012-05-16 09:55:37.3870000
John      Import12  2012-05-16 09:55:37.3840000
Sasha     Import12  2012-05-16 09:55:37.3850000
(null)    Import12  2012-05-16 09:55:37.3870000
Ann       Imp01     2012-05-16 09:54:02.4780000
Mark      Imp01     2012-05-16 09:54:02.4770000
Sam       Imp01     2012-05-16 09:54:02.4770000
(null)    Imp01     2012-05-16 09:54:02.4780000
```

Live test: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c7859/23

---

How it works:

```
with grp(Name,ImpFile,TimeGroup,ImpTime) as 
(
  select cast(null as varchar(5)), ImpFile, max(ImpTime) as TimeGroup, 
         max(ImpTime) as ImpTime
  from people 
  group by ImpFile  

  union all

  select p.Name, p.ImpFile, ldr.TimeGroup, p.ImpTime
  from people p
  inner join grp ldr -- leader
  on ldr.name is null and ldr.ImpFile = p.ImpFile
)
select *
from grp 
order by TimeGroup desc, Name;
```

Output:

```
NAME      IMPFILE   IMPTIME                       TIMEGROUP
(null)    Import12  2012-05-16 09:55:37.3870000   2012-05-16 09:55:37.3870000
Bart      Import12  2012-05-16 09:55:37.3870000   2012-05-16 09:55:37.3870000
John      Import12  2012-05-16 09:55:37.3840000   2012-05-16 09:55:37.3870000
Sasha     Import12  2012-05-16 09:55:37.3850000   2012-05-16 09:55:37.3870000
(null)    Imp01     2012-05-16 09:54:02.4780000   2012-05-16 09:54:02.4780000
Ann       Imp01     2012-05-16 09:54:02.4780000   2012-05-16 09:54:02.4780000
Mark      Imp01     2012-05-16 09:54:02.4770000   2012-05-16 09:54:02.4780000
Sam       Imp01     2012-05-16 09:54:02.4770000   2012-05-16 09:54:02.4780000
```

Live test: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c7859/25

Comment: Nice one. I was thinking of something similar, but did not know how to exactly do that, so thanks man. :)

Answer (score 6):

Why can you just do it like this:

```
order by ImpFile DESC, ImpTime desc
```

No it do not result in what you are showing. It result in this:

```
        Import12    2012-05-16 09:55:37.387
Bart    Import12    2012-05-16 09:55:37.387
Sasha   Import12    2012-05-16 09:55:37.387
John    Import12    2012-05-16 09:55:37.383
        Imp01       2012-05-16 09:54:02.477
Ann     Imp01       2012-05-16 09:54:02.477
Mark    Imp01       2012-05-16 09:54:02.477
Sam     Imp01       2012-05-16 09:54:02.477
```

See [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2e0bb/1) for an example

**EDIT**

I have a suggestion for you. Maybe something like this:

**Test data**

```
DECLARE @T TABLE(Name VARCHAR(100),ImpFile VARCHAR(100),ImpTime DATETIME)

INSERT INTO @T
    ([Name], [ImpFile], [ImpTime])
VALUES
    ('Sam', 'Imp01', '2012-05-16 09:54:02.477'),
    ('Ann', 'Imp01', '2012-05-16 09:54:02.478'),
    ('Mark', 'Imp01', '2012-05-16 09:54:02.477'),
    ('John', 'Import12', '2012-05-16 09:55:37.384'),
    ('Bart', 'Import12', '2012-05-16 09:55:37.387'),
    ('Sasha', 'Import12', '2012-05-16 09:55:37.385');
```

**Query**

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(   
    SELECT
        ROW_Number() OVER(PARTITION BY  t.[ImpFile] 
                     ORDER BY t.[ImpTime] DESC) AS RowNbr,
        '' AS Name,
        t.ImpFile,
        t.[ImpTime]
    FROM
        @T AS t
)
SELECT
    CTE.Name,
    CTE.ImpFile,
    CTE.[ImpTime],
    0 as SortOrder
FROM
    CTE
WHERE
    CTE.RowNbr=1
UNION ALL
SELECT
    t.Name,
    t.ImpFile,
    t.[ImpTime],
    1 as SortOrder
FROM
    @T AS t
ORDER BY
    ImpFile DESC,SortOrder, ImpTime desc
```

Comment: I have edited my post, to show you what happens when I do like this

Comment: this is only part of my table, maybe these ones give the result like this, but there are records, where the result is what I showed

Comment: If you do not secure this particular order, it cannot be guaranteed. You must specify it in your `ORDER BY` explicitly that every aggregated row should go at the beginning of its respective group. The OP is right, the output in your example merely *happens* to be the one that is required. With a larger dataset, it can be different.

Comment: Ok. Updated the answer have a look.

Comment: This must be closer, but it still does not guarantee that summary rows (those with empty Names) would go before their respective detail rows. You could get `(empty name)`, then `Bart`, or just the other way around. I think you might need an additional column to show which rows are details and which are summary (and use that column in sorting somehow).

Comment: I get what you are saying. I updated the answer with your suggestions. Thanks for pointing that out. You are almost hunting me :P. Why the downvote? Are you happy with that solution?

Comment: :) I am not hunting you, but I *have* been following this comment thread because you do not reference my name (using `@`) when replying me and so I do not get notifications about your replies. As for the downvote, that's not mine, but someone might have noticed the same issues I did, and that was their reaction.

Comment: Almost forgot. :) I think your answer is fine now. It is simpler than mine but that's partly because it doesn't assume that groups should be ordered by the max times (which may just be unnecessary too). Anyway, +1, this must be worth testing by the OP, I think.

Comment: @AndriyM : Sorry I did not use the `@` sign. Thanks for the +1. I also think the OP Should test it.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you should realise that with the `datetime` type's granularity, SQL Server is unable to distinguish between `2012-05-16 09:55:37.384` and `2012-05-16 09:55:37.385`: both would be stored as `2012-05-16 09:55:37.384`.

Bearing that in mind and assuming that you want to sort the groups by `MAX(ImpTime) DESC` as well as the detail rows by `ImpTime DESC`, you could try something like this:

```
WITH agg AS (
  SELECT
    *,
    ImpTimeMax = MAX(ImpTime) OVER (PARTITION BY ImpFile),
    rn         = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ImpFile ORDER BY ImpTime DESC)
  FROM Table1
)
SELECT
  Name = CASE x.IsAgg WHEN 1 THEN '' ELSE agg.Name END,
  agg.ImpFile,
  agg.ImpTime
FROM agg
  INNER JOIN (SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 1) x (IsAgg) ON x.IsAgg = 0 OR agg.rn = 1
ORDER BY
  agg.ImpTimeMax DESC,  /* the primary order for groups */
  agg.ImpFile    ASC ,  /* in case two or more groups have the same max time */
  x.IsAgg        DESC,  /* the group summary row goes first */
  agg.ImpTime    DESC,  /* or: agg.rn ASC */
  agg.Name       ASC    /* in case two or more people have the same time */
```

When run [on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ccbc1/3), this produces the following output for your example:

```
NAME   IMPFILE   IMPTIME
-----  --------  -----------------------
       Import12  2012-05-16 09:55:37.387
Bart   Import12  2012-05-16 09:55:37.387
Sasha  Import12  2012-05-16 09:55:37.385
John   Import12  2012-05-16 09:55:37.384
       Imp01     2012-05-16 09:54:02.478
Ann    Imp01     2012-05-16 09:54:02.478
Mark   Imp01     2012-05-16 09:54:02.477
Sam    Imp01     2012-05-16 09:54:02.477
```

And note that I temporarily defined `ImpTime` as a `varchar`, not as a `datetime`, just for the sake of a better demonstration, because, like I said, `datetime`'s granularity would result in slightly different values stored (and, accordingly, slightly different output produced).

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to scrub the milliseconds: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/35065/2

```
select Name, ImpFile, 

   ImpTimeX = 
      DATEADD(ms, -DATEPART(ms, ImpTime), ImpTime)

from tbl

union

select distinct '', ImpFile, 

   ImpTimeX = 
       MAX(DATEADD(ms, -DATEPART(ms, ImpTime), ImpTime))

from tbl 
group by ImpFile
order by ImpTimeX desc, Name
```

Output:

```
NAME           IMPFILE        IMPTIMEX
               Import12       May, 16 2012 09:55:37-0700
Bart           Import12       May, 16 2012 09:55:37-0700
John           Import12       May, 16 2012 09:55:37-0700
Sasha          Import12       May, 16 2012 09:55:37-0700
               Imp01          May, 16 2012 09:54:02-0700
Ann            Imp01          May, 16 2012 09:54:02-0700
Mark           Imp01          May, 16 2012 09:54:02-0700
Sam            Imp01          May, 16 2012 09:54:02-0700
```

Technique for scrubbing the milliseconds sourced here: [SQL Server remove milliseconds from datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286849/sql-server-remove-milliseconds-from-datetime)

---

If you want to retain and show the original time, just do this: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/35065/1

```
with a as(

  select Name, ImpFile, 

     ImpTimeX = 
        DATEADD(ms, -DATEPART(ms, ImpTime), ImpTime),

     ImpTime

  from tbl

  union

  select distinct '', ImpFile, 

     ImpTimeX = 
         MAX(DATEADD(ms, -DATEPART(ms, ImpTime), ImpTime)),

     MAX(ImpTime)

  from tbl 
  group by ImpFile

)
select Name, ImpFile, ImpTime
from a
order by ImpTimeX desc, Name
```

I think SqlFiddle doesn't show the milliseconds. Please try the second query on your Sql Server there, I'm currently on other OS now, I cannot see the second query's actual output

---

Here's the output of the second query, with the datetime intact, tested on SSMS:

```
Name    ImpFile         ImpTime     
        Import12        2012-05-16 09:55:37.3870000
Bart    Import12        2012-05-16 09:55:37.3870000
John    Import12        2012-05-16 09:55:37.3840000
Sasha   Import12        2012-05-16 09:55:37.3850000
        Imp01           2012-05-16 09:54:02.4780000
Ann     Imp01           2012-05-16 09:54:02.4780000
Mark    Imp01           2012-05-16 09:54:02.4770000
Sam     Imp01           2012-05-16 09:54:02.4770000
```

Comment: At these two datasets the milliseconds don't mater, but I have in my table a lot of more data, where there are +/- 2 seconds with the same impFile. And in that case the order is only partly corect.

Comment: Have a look at my output, it adheres to your desired output. Check the the live test here too: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/35065/1

Comment: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/35065/1 at the result where ImpFile is "Import12" John should come before Sasha, because at the alphabet "J" comes before "S"

Comment: Yet your requirement is to sort descending on time, isn't it? How can John come before Sasha then? look at your data: Bart(.387), John(.384), Sasha(.385).  If we sort that by descending time: Bart(.387), Sasha(.385), John(.384)   How can John be first than Sasha, if the first part of your requirement is to sort by descending time(and then sort by name) ?

Comment: well that is the point, I need that the first query where it gets only ImpFile and ImpTime is sorted by ImpTime descending, but the query where I get also Names is sorted by Name. maybe there is a way to do that? To order each union query separately

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `order by` is only getting applied to the second `select` in your `union` query.

Try using a `subselect` to create a temporary table to apply the `order by` to:

```
select Name, ImpFile, ImpTime from (
select Name, ImpFile, ImpTime from people
union
select distinct '', ImpFile, max(ImpTime) from people group by ImpFile
) order by ImpTime desc, Name
```

Comment: Answered from smartphone; I'll verify the query when I get to a computer, it should work.

Comment: This is the same as the OP's query. ORDER BY on UNION applies to the whole query, not just the last query. So the parenthesis in your query is superfluous

Comment: Look at the two queries here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/22aeb/2 They are both identical in behavior

Answer (score 0):

You can get the desired output with order by ImpFile desc,Name

```
select Name, ImpFile, ImpTime
    from dbo.tbl_stack 
    union
    select distinct '', ImpFile, max(ImpTime)
    from dbo.tbl_stack 
    group by ImpFile
    order by ImpFile desc,Name
```

Here's the output

```
Name    ImpFile         ImpTime 
        Import12        2012-05-16 09:55:37.387
Bar     Import12        2012-05-16 09:55:37.387
John    Import12        2012-05-16 09:55:37.383
Sasha   Import12        2012-05-16 09:55:37.387
        Imp01       2012-05-16 09:54:02.477
Ann     Imp01       2012-05-16 09:54:02.477
Mark    Imp01       2012-05-16 09:54:02.477
Sam     Imp01           2012-05-16 09:54:02.477
```