# sql order by based on two columns

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table which store id, price and availability of a product. I want to list products based on the lowest price first but these products should be available. The products which have lower price but are not available should be listed in sorted order below the products which may have higher price but are available.

suppose this is the data in the table

```
id | price | availability
8247|16690.0|true
8247|16500.0|true
8247|16000.0|false
8247|15999.0|false
```

I want a query which returns me data in this form

```
id | price | availability
8247|16500.0|true
8247|16690.0|true
8247|15999.0|false
8247|16000.0|false
```

How can this be done ?

The table schema is

```
sqlite> .schema pricecomparison
CREATE TABLE `pricecomparison` (`availability` VARCHAR , `id` VARCHAR , `price` VARCHAR );
```

Comment: Show us the SQL you have tried.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10615284/order-by-multiple-columns

Answer (score 6):

Maybe something like this:

```
ORDER BY availability DESC, price
```

Additional information:

- [SQLite - ORDER BY Clause](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_order_by.htm)

Comment: sqlite> select id, price, availability from pricecomparison where id = 8247 order by availability, price;
8247|15999.0|false
8247|16000.0|false
8247|16500.0|true
8247|16690.0|true

Comment: What is the type of `availability`? If it is `text`, you need to sort `DESC` on it because `true` comes after `false`.

Comment: all the columns are varchar

Comment: @Tichodroma : The `availability DESC` should work if it is varchars. Thanks for the update

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM pricecomparison ORDER BY availability DESC,price
```

I add `DESC` to provide `true` first.

Comment: Please add an explaination why you think that this solves the problem. Otherwise, it lacks context and is likely to be removed due to “low quality”.