# How to I order by a sql table multiple times?

Tags: sql

I don't think I worded it correctly but how do I use order by to sort a table multiple times by a different dimension. For example if I wanted to sort by type of priority of deadlines first (soft, hard, late) then if two inputs have the same priority type, I sort by the duration of the task, then by another parameter, how do I go about doing that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [order by multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10615284/order-by-multiple-columns)

Comment: What database type are you trying to query? Also maybe include the create statement for your table.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
FROM table_name
ORDER BY column1, column2, ... ASC|DESC;
```

You automatically order by the other columns mentioned right after your primary ORDER BY column(column1).

Comment: column1 is your priority order, column2 is second prio if two entries got the same value for column1. hope that helps!