# Select a datetime in Tsql, trim the milliseconds and return as a string

Tags: t-sql, datetime

Problem: I want to select a date (stored as datetime) and return is as a **string** with the milliseconds trimmed off.

```
eg  2017-01-04 08:47:30.0000000 => "2017-01-04 08:47:30"
```

My current solutions:

I have got 3 statements which do the above:

Substring option

```
 select  
    SUBSTRING(CONVERT(nvarchar,EventDate),0,20) 
 from  EventsTable
```

Double convertions

```
select  
     CONVERT(nvarchar, CONVERT(datetime2(0),EventDate))  
from  EventsTable
```

Short nvarchar

```
select  
   CONVERT(nvarchar(19),EventDate) 
from  EventsTable
```

Allof the above solutions work and achieve my goal.

Question:
What is the best practice / most efficient way to achieve my goal?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286849/sql-server-remove-milliseconds-from-datetime

Comment: The best practise is to simply return a datetime, and let your presentation layer deal with the formatting. You should also [**always** specify a length when converting to, or declaring `CHAR/NCHAR/VARCHAR/NVARCHAR`](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length). There is also no need at all to use `NVARCHAR`, you are expecting a date in the format `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss`, there will not be any nonunicode characters so `VARCHAR` will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use a date style in your convert:

```
select CONVERT(varchar(19),EventDate,120)
from  EventsTable
```

I would use this. It uses only one function, and sets the correct length for the varchar, and the format tells SQL Server the correct format you need.

Since style 120 is a standard you are sure that it the same no matter what localisation settings are on your DB or Session.

Comment: By the way, when I try your 3 pieces of code on my session, with Danish settings I get these replies:
`Jan  9 2017 11:38AM

2017-01-09 11:38:24

Jan  9 2017 11:38AM`

Comment: Sorry, I had trouble with the formatting of the comment, my point was that I get two formatting of the dates, which is why I would recommen always making sure you get the correct style, by using it in the convert, like in my answer, or by explicitly setting the region dateformat

Answer (score 0):

I ran all the three queries with the Execution Plan enabled with SQL Server 2008R2.

I received the cost equal in all of them ( 33% each).

All the three queries take the same time and resources.

However, the third one might help you with the less code being written.