# Remove the zeros using SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

Hello I am using SQL Server and I have this column :

```
data
6/19/2019 3:10:12 PM
12/23/2016 5:02:15 AM
```

I wanted to extract only the time so I used the following query :

```
select try_parse([data] as time using 'en-US') from Table_1
```

But the problem is I get as a result this :

```
15:10:12.0000000
05:02:15.0000000
```

All is okay except the 0 I mean I would like to get :

```
15:10:12
05:02:15
```

Thank you very much for your help !

Comment: `time` has a scale. Try `time(0)`.  On a different note, why are you storing dates as a `varchar` and not a `datetime` or `datetime2`? Also, `TRY_PARSE` and `time` were introduced in SQL Server 2012, however, you've tagged SQL Server 2008 and 2005?

Comment: Before you go any further you should take some time to understand data types. Also it's important to understand that this kind of formatting is usually best achieved in the 'presentation layer'. If this is for a report or an application then format it in there, not in the database.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server remove milliseconds from datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286849/sql-server-remove-milliseconds-from-datetime)

Comment: You can cast the column to a time as follows.I am assuming that the column "data" is a date datatype. If yes then,     select cast(data as time) from table_1

Answer (score 2):

You can use `TIME()` with the correct scale to get your desired results.

`select Convert(time(0) , Data ) as time from Table_1`

`time(0)` means a scale of 0, which has a precision of 8. This results as `HH:MM:SS`. Using another scale, like 1, would give you a single digit for the fractional second. You can read up on all of the scales in the [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/time-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @data varchar(28)='12/23/2016 5:02:15 AM'

select Convert(varchar(20),Cast(@data as time),24)
```

Comment: be sure to add context to your answer, it will help a lot

Comment: Also, there is no benefit to converting this to a varchar. Quite the opposite, actually.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select CONVERT(varchar(8),  data, 108) from Table_1
```

that only show time (17:00:59) but you can add + between them if you want full format date as dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss

```
select CONVERT(varchar(10), data, 101) + ' ' + CONVERT(varchar(8), data, 108) from Table_1
```

They will work if data using DATETIME type

Answer (score 0):

You can extract time using below query

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), cast('12/23/2016 5:02:15 AM' as time),108)
```

The output is- `05:02:15`. I can hope this query/answer is self explanatory.