# Get data in a specific date for a time range with a minute difference

Tags: c#, linq, date-range, between

I have the following datetime range:

> 22/07/2021 07:00:52 (start date)
> 22/07/2021 07:01:00 (end date)

I want all the data between this range including the right hand boundary.

My linq to SQL query:

```
Select * from tableName where CreatedAt >= startDate and CreateAt <= endDate
```

The issue here with the query is I am unable to get the record whose CreatedAt= 22/07/2021 07:01:00 (end date). If I do AddMinutes(1) to the endDate, I get the required datas but I also get the data greater than endDate.
For example data having following Created At dates

> 22/07/2021 07:01:15
> 22/07/2021 07:01:20

which is faulty.

How do I include the right boundary in the range comparison for datetime?

I have tried removing the miliseconds from the database record as:

```
select *  from Custom_Devices  
where
DATEADD(ms, -DATEPART(ms, CreatedAt), CreatedAt) >= '2019-07-29
19:00:00' 
and 
DATEADD(ms, -DATEPART(ms, CreatedAt), CreatedAt) <= 
'2019-07-29 19:01:00'
```

Attaching a screenshot of the output:
[image]

Expected output:
[image]

Update: **CreatedAt column is a datetime2 column in database.**

Comment: If the dates store the milliseconds (not set to `0` when the date is created), add 1 second. Otherwise, add 1 millisecond (to `endDate`).

Comment: In this case, `CreateAt < endDate` (not `<=`)

Comment: Looks like the Date Value in the database have milliseconds part in it, that's why comparing it with the data with seconds precision for equality will not return true. You need to compare the dates with removing milliseconds from the date from the database... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286849/sql-server-remove-milliseconds-from-datetime

Comment: @Chetan, tried removing the ms but no luck.

Comment: Can you share the code which tried removing the ms? @Mellionis

Comment: @Chetan, here it is:
`select * 
from Custom_Devices 
where DATEADD(ms, -DATEPART(ms, CreatedAt), CreatedAt) >= '2019-07-29 19:00:00'
and DATEADD(ms, -DATEPART(ms, CreatedAt), CreatedAt) <= '2019-07-29 19:01:00'`

Comment: hmm.. can you share sample data from your table? Also it's better if you share the code in the question itself instead of writing in the comment... did you try running `select DATEADD(ms, -DATEPART(ms, CreatedAt), CreatedAt) from Custom_Devices`, what output do you get?

Comment: To include all the times 19:01:00.x where x != 0 then rather test for `< 19:01:01`

Comment: if you want to drop the milliseconds from the datetime2 value, you can cast it to `smalldatetime` before comparing.... so you query should look like `select * from Custom_Devices  
where
cast(createdat AS smalldatetime) >= '2019-07-29T19:00:00' 
and 
cast(createdat AS smalldatetime) <= '2019-07-29T19:01:00'`

Comment: @Chetan, it seems to be working but I have to CAST the column from linq. Anyway to achieve it? smalldatetime equivalent in C# so that it can translate to SQL without any exception.

Comment: @Chetan no; do not manipulate table data for queries that can be solved using ranges. Manipulating table data kills indexing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> f I do AddMinutes(1) to the endDate

Not sure why you'd add a whole minute when the problem is caused by additional milliseconds and can be solved by going up a second..

Do you actually want to keep the milliseconds on the dates? Is it any use to you to know that the event occurred at 12:34.56.789 rather than 12:34:56? If not, make the column a datetime2(0) to discard the milliseconds permanently

Otherwise I recommend the route several other people are also advocating and do your LINQ like

```
context.Whatever.Where(x => x.CreatedAt >= startDate && x.CreatedAt < endDate.AddSeconds(1))
```

The "less than" is vital. A "less than 12:34:57" will get 12:34:56.999999... which appears to be what you want with your "less than or equal to 12:34:56"

If you're struggling to understand why milliseconds cause a problem, think of dates like numbers - if you have a number 1.222222 and you ask the db for "less than or equal to 1.2" the DB doesn't auto-round the 1.222222 down to 1 decimal place and then go "oh it's equal to 1.2" and return it. It just goes "1.222222 is not less than or equal to 1.2, don't return it"

Over time for question like this you'll always get someone who says "just cast it to.." or "run this to calculate a new date to remove the milliseconds..." - don't; if you write a query that manipulates the table data, that manipulation has to be performed every time the data is queried. It typically kills the ability for the db to use an index on the column too (the db will probably switch to running the manipulation on every value in the index, every time) which means the query is massively more resource intensive.

Always consider manipulating table data in a where clause as an absolute last resort. If there is no other way and the query will be heavily used, look at adding some kind of calculated column to the table and index it so that, conceptually, the result of the manipulation you're carrying out is done once and an index on it can be used

Comment: I cannot remove the milliseconds on dates. Probably, going ahead adding a second to the endDate is a better approach.

Comment: Your dba will thank you for it, certainly! :D

Comment: Damn!! why didn't I think of adding a second? Probably because they were actually getting truncated somewhere along the way. :D. But adding a second fixes my issue.

Comment: Don't worry, SO is full of questions that are "so obvious I just missed it" - I'd be lying if I said it's never happened to me 