# Check if DateTime has time or not

Tags: c#, reflection, expression

Say I have a database column 'A'. The type of column in DB can either be Date or DateTime. I am creating a dynamic filter query:

```
filterFragment = Expression.AndAlso(
                            Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(memberExpression, Expression.Constant(beginDate)),
                                Expression.LessThan(memberExpression, Expression.Constant(endDate.AddSeconds(1))));
```

where,

```
memberExpression = Expression.Property(rootExpression, property);
rootExpression = Expression.Parameter(targetType, targetType.Name);
queryableSource = source.AsQueryable();
results = queryableSource.Expression;
targetType = queryableSource.ElementType;
```

and

> ```
> IEnumerable<TSource> source is a parameter to the method generating the dynamic filterExpression.
> ```

Attached a screenshot of memberExpression value during runtime:
[image]

and here's the Type value:

[image]

How do I check if the Type of memberExpression has Time part or it is a ShortDate without any time part? The reason I want to check the type of memberExpression is that if it has Time part I need to do endDate.AddSecond(1), and if there isn't a time part need to use LessThanOrEqual in Expression as:

```
filterFragment = Expression.AndAlso(
                            Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(memberExpression, Expression.Constant(beginDate)),
                                Expression.LessThanOrEqual(memberExpression, Expression.Constant(endDate)));
```

More details of question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68735238/get-data-in-a-specific-date-for-a-time-range-with-a-minute-difference/68736579#68736579).

Comment: Why not just always add a millisecond and always use lessthan? But from a c# perspective a DateTime always has a time, and its equal to midnight if it's imported from a sql DATE, hence you could check if `someDate == someDate.Date`

Comment: I would add a millisecond, but I am not sure what the type of my database column would be as mentioned.

Comment: "beginDate" and "endDate" seem to represent the values that are either Date or DateTime. Isn't the the DataType of the parameter supposed to be declared somewhere in that context? (I am not so much familiar with Expressions)

Comment: @lidqy, I can know what the data type of the beginDate and endDate are, but what I want to know is the datatype of the coloumn against which I am comparing the dates with.

Comment: And the dataytpe of the column can be different from the datatype of a value of that column?

Comment: Or are SQL Date and DateTime both mapped to .NET DateTime?

Comment: @lidqy, SQL Date and DateTime are both mapped to .Net DateTime

Comment: Is there somewhere in the API a way to query the underlying mapped SQL Data Type of a column / entity's property?

Comment: And is that expression code being translated back to SQL before it executes? Or does it execute on the data in memory which is just allocated as .NET types...
If it's not translated back, you might just the add the second as @CaiusJard proposed. If it runs as SQL you need to query the SQL data type ....

Comment: The expression code is translated back to SQL before it executes and there isn't any API to get the type of data of the column.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017l&fiddle=e439b6e0787451d84d0878a8a4dd09d6 ?

Comment: @CaiusJard, AddSeconds won't work because even if we add seconds the time part will be truncated before the comparison with DB data thus returning undesired data.

Comment: It is a duplicate question
please check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15893339/check-if-date-time-string-contains-time

Comment: Does this answer your question? [check if date time string contains time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15893339/check-if-date-time-string-contains-time)