# How to improve performance for datetime filtering in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a problem with filtering by `datetime` columns.

I tried these two methods:

```
datefield < '2013-03-15 17:17:55.179'
datefield < CAST('2013-03-15 17:17:55.179' AS datetime)
```

I have a large database with over 3.000.000 main objects.

So I need to improve performance for my `datetime` filtering. I was reading about UNIX timestamp (convert all `datetime` to UNIX timestamp and then filter by this UNIX field).

I think it's a better way than filtering by `datetime`. But if anyone knows some other way, I would appreciate it.

My query is:

```
SELECT TOP (100)  ev.Title as Event_name, po.Name as POI_name, 
po.Address, po.City, po.Region, po.Country, po.Latitude, po.Longitude, ev.Start_time, 
(Select ID_Category FROM SubCategory s where ev.ID_SubCategory = s.ID_SubCategory) as ID_Category, 
ev.ID_SubCategory, ev.ID_Event, ev.ID_Channel, IDChanelEvent, 
ev.FavoriteCount, po.gmtOffset, v.IsFavorite, v1.IsFavorite  
FROM Events ev 
JOIN POI po ON ev.ID_POI = po.ID_POI 
JOIN (SELECT et.id_event as joinIdEv FROM EventTagLink et, tags t 
 WHERE t.id_tag = et.id_tag 
 AND ( t.Title = N'music' ) 
 ) as joinEvents 
 ON joinEvents.joinIdEv = ev.ID_Event 
LEFT JOIN Viewed v ON v.ID_Event = ev.ID_Event AND v.ID_User = 1 AND v.IsFavorite = 1 LEFT join Viewed v1 ON v1.ID_Event = ev.ID_Event AND v1.ID_User = 1 AND v1.IsFavorite = 0
WHERE 
--ev.GmtStop_time > '2013-03-15 14:17:55.188' AND 
po.Latitude > 41.31423 AND po.Latitude < 61.60511 
AND  po.Longitude > -6.676602 AND po.Longitude < 17.04498  
AND ev.ID_SubCategory in (3, 12, 21, 4, 30, 13, 22, 6, 14, 40, 23, 7, 32, 15, 41, 8, 50, 33, 16, 42, 25, 9, 34, 17, 35, 18, 44, 27, 36, 19, 45, 28, 37, 46, 29, 38, 47, 39, 48, 49, 10, 1, 11, 2, 20) 
--AND ev.GmtStart_time< '2013-03-15 17:17:55.179'
AND v1.IsFavorite is null
```

filtering by the time I commented.

If I turn off these filters, request duration is several seconds. If I turn them on then request duration is over 25 seconds.

- [Execution plan with filtering datetime](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xjnu5om2r7yru04/execution_plan.sqlplan)
- [Execution plan without datetime filter](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0ab15b7nuamlw8s/execution_plan_without_datefilter.sqlplan)

So there is a lot of discussion about execute plans, indexes and so on. But what about **UNIX timestamp**, which is the main reason why I've put the question there. **Would it improve performance for `datetime` filtering?**

Comment: Do you have an index on `datefield` column?

Comment: First: make sure you have a relevant index on that column. Secondly: don't use any **functions** (like `CAST`) on your datetime columns in `WHERE` expressions

Comment: yes.  It's helps but not enough

Comment: i don't use CAST i just try

Comment: maybe it's not your "datetime" filtering - but something else in your query?

Comment: About unix timestamp how do u think. Can it help me? I investigate facebook api and saw that all datatime field have a unix timestamp type

Comment: There is not enough information here to know what the problem is. You need to show the entire SQL and then tell us what you expect from it, ie. how many rows you expect it to return, how much time you expect/want it to consume, how much time it actually consumes, etc.

Comment: I am sure that is datime filtering

Comment: If your query with the filter returns big part of rows, say 2 mln out of 3 mln, you cannot do anything to optimize it except reduce number of rows returned.

Comment: Depending on **how many** rows out of your total of 3 million your criteria matches, it will not be filtering much - but that would be absolutely the same with "unix timestamp" filtering or whatever else. If you query asks for 20, 50% of the data - it will **always** be slow. No magic bullet here....

Comment: Please show us the complete query. Why do you think the query runs slow? Maybe its just as fast as your hardware? The query should perform similar to other queries on the same table with differently typed columns in the where-statement (under comparable conditions: both columns indexed ...).

Comment: What type your datefield column? It could be implicit cast if types of column and filter variable are dont match

Comment: Type of datetime fields is "datetime"

Comment: I need to get just 100 items.

Comment: You need to paste the execution plan into your question.

Answer (score 55):

Just a suggestion when it comes to indexes on datetime in msql is the index footprint impacts search times (Yes this seems obvious...but please read onward).

The importances to this when indexing on the datetime say for instance '2015-06-05 22:47:20.102' the index has to account for every place within the datetime. This becomes very large spatially and bulky. A successful approach that I've leveraged is create a new datetime column and populate the data by rounding the time to the hour and then building the index upon this new column. Example '2015-06-05 22:47:20.102' translates to '2015-06-05 22:00:00.000'. By taking this approach we leave the detailed data alone and can display it or use it by search on this new column which gives us approximately a 10x (at minimum) return on how fast results are returned. This is due to the fact that the index doesn't have to account for the minutes, seconds and millisecond fields.

Comment: You answer led me to investigate, that I can improve performance by reducing datetimeoffset precision to seconds (remove miliseconds) by using [datetimeoffset](0). http://stackoverflow.com/a/2247898/507699

Comment: BTREE indexes, on any data type, have spatial complexity O(size * log(size)) where size is the volume of data being indexed. The idea that a higher precision value causes great bloat in the index size is not correct.

Comment: @Sean any proof? Why wood the index care what's inside the time value? It only cares about =, <, >.

Comment: I'm thinking that indexing a date including the time is a bad idea in almost all instances.  It is essentially saying that you are comfortable never getting an exact match in any search criteria involving that field.  I would suggest having two fields, one for the date, one for the time and indexing on them both.  Then your date searches will always find exact matches , getting you to the relevant data faster.  Then you can filter for time within that data set.

Comment: Changing the granularity of the index key does not change the number of rows in the index, which is what primarily dictates the index size. Only if you additionally applied page compression would the index size itself be noticeably reduced, and even then this reduction in size would only be noticeable for index scans, not seeks. As a thought exercise, imagine an index that stored only the year (and so "rounded" all the rows to `2015`, but still had to index all the rows) to see why this doesn't really help. If a brand new index "helps", it's likely just because the old one is fragmented.

Comment: I round it to Date with no time in my projects and create an index against that. So I have two columns in db (DateTime with no index and Date with index) and my query looks like "WHERE Date <= 'MyDateTime.Date' and DateTime < 'MyDateTime'". I think the Microsoft should add the ability to round values when index is built. So we don't have to create two columns.
Based on the situation you might need to round to Month.
P.S. Creating indexes against DateTime columns won't increase you performance but rather decrease it.

Comment: @OleksandrFentsyk . . . I would respectfully suggest that you unaccept this answer.  The OP does not seem to understand how indexes work and is propagating misleading information.

Comment: Footprint definitely matters. More data means more io, regardless of how/what you index.

Answer (score 5):

You need to look at your execution plan first to see what SQL Server is doing. More than likely, you just need add an index. Little conversions like this are almost never the reason why your query is slow. Indices are a good first stop for fixing queries.

You don't need to make this the clustered index. Making it the clustered index means that you don't need to do a lookup, but for only 100 rows, lookup is very fast. I would put datetime and subcategory into a nonclustered index, in that order.

If you are ordering, you should also make sure that's in an index. Since it only makes sense to use one index per table, you'll need to make sure all the relevant columns are in the same index, in the right order.

But first, get your actual execution plan!

Comment: 2. In main table i have a lot of index that execution plan was ask me. Each of this index have some included columns. How do you think. Should I combine them?

Comment: Is it possible for you to post the plan in your question?

I would start without the included columns, and then include them if you think that performance is poor. Included columns increase the maintenance of your index and need to be modified every time you add a column to your table. I would not include them unless the lookup time is large.

Comment: I add to question execution plan. Take a look on it

Comment: @SashaFencyk This is very interesting. The most expensive parts of your query are your Index Seeks and RID Lookup. Furthermore, the total is greater than 100%. I don't see how this could be 25x slower. Are the run times consistently 25x slower? Can you also post the original query's execution plan? Is there some lock contention going on?

Comment: You were right about indexes. I was just going to chuck them left right and centre. I took your advise, did an execution plan and realised the query was instant... more digging led to a very bad series of rubbish... optimized that and everything runs like a dream again. No indexes addded! +1 +beer

Answer (score 2):

For better performance I suggest you create new indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX x1 ON LiveCity.dbo.Tags(Title) INCLUDE(ID_Tag)
CREATE INDEX x2 ON LiveCity.dbo.Tags(ID_Event, GmtStart_time, GmtStop_time) 
  INCLUDE(
          FavoriteCount, 
          ID_Channel, 
          ID_POI, 
          ID_SubCategory, 
          IDChanelEvent, 
          Start_time, 
          Title
          )
CREATE INDEX x ON LiveCity.dbo.POI(ID_POI, Latitude, Longitude) 
  INCLUDE(
          Address, 
          City, 
          Country, 
          gmtOffset, 
          Name, 
          Region
          )
```

This will help you avoid RID lookup operation and improve the overall performance of the query.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one -

```
;WITH cte AS (
     SELECT IsFavorite, ID_Event  
     FROM Viewed
     WHERE ID_User = 1 
)
SELECT TOP (100)
      Event_name = ev.Title 
    , POI_name = po.Name 
    , po.[address]
    , po.City
    , po.Region
    , po.Country
    , po.Latitude
    , po.Longitude
    , ev.start_time
    , s.ID_Category
    , ev.ID_SubCategory
    , ev.ID_Event
    , ev.ID_Channel
    , IDChanelEvent
    , ev.FavoriteCount
    , po.gmtOffset
    , v.IsFavorite
    , IsFavorite = NULL
FROM [events] ev
JOIN POI po ON ev.ID_POI = po.ID_POI
LEFT JOIN SubCategory s ON ev.ID_SubCategory = s.ID_SubCategory
LEFT JOIN cte v ON v.ID_Event = ev.ID_Event AND v.IsFavorite = 1
WHERE po.Latitude BETWEEN 41.31423 AND 61.60511
     AND po.Longitude BETWEEN -6.676602 AND 17.04498
     AND ev.ID_SubCategory IN (3, 12, 21, 4, 30, 13, 22, 6, 14, 40, 23, 7, 32, 15, 41, 8, 50, 33, 16, 42, 25, 9, 34, 17, 35, 18, 44, 27, 36, 19, 45, 28, 37, 46, 29, 38, 47, 39, 48, 49, 10, 1, 11, 2, 20)
     AND v1.IsFavorite IS NULL
     AND EXISTS(
          SELECT 1 
          FROM EventTagLink et
          WHERE t.Title = 'music'
               AND et.joinIdEv = ev.ID_Event
     )
     AND NOT EXISTS (
          SELECT * 
          FROM cte v1 
          WHERE v1.ID_Event = ev.ID_Event AND v1.IsFavorite = 0
     )
```

Answer (score -9):

Create cluster index on datetime field it will definitely help . we faced same problem earlier . we solved it by creating index on datetime column .

Comment: yes , cluster index will give better performance over non cluster indexes because ultimately non cluster index use cluster indexes internally . Can you give me sample database ? I want to play with it . I really interested to do this type of stuff.

Comment: Seriously? @SashaFencyk, don't give people here direct access to either your data *or* to your server.

Comment: Thanks for caring @MikeSherrill'Catcall'. I understand that)