# MySQL Query with three un-indexed unionized tables and a left join overburdens DB

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, left-join, union-all

I have a rather complex SQL Query and i don't know how to do it less complex. If i try to run it, it overburdens the db. If i simplify it a little, i can execute it but it takes a lot of time. 
I'm sure there are much more efficient ways to write this query but i have no idea how. Would be very glad if someone could lead me in the right direction!

```
SELECT master.C_MASTER_ID,
       master.C_MASTER_SUMMARY,
       master.C_MASTER_START,
       master.C_MASTER_END,
       master.C_MASTER_LEVEL,
       master.C_MASTER_SOURCE,
       NULL AS EVT_HAS_Z,
       master.C_MASTER_NOTES,
       master.C_MASTER_SERVICE,
       c2c.CER_CUSTOMER
FROM `C_MASTER` master
LEFT JOIN `c2customer` c2c ON c2c.CER_ID = master.C_MASTER_ID
WHERE 
  master.C_MASTER_END >= NOW()
  AND master.C_MASTER_START >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 21 DAY)

UNION ALL

SELECT EVT_ID AS C_MASTER_ID,
       EVT_SUMMARY,
       EVT_START_DATE,
       EVT_END_DATE,
       NULL AS C_MASTER_LEVEL,
       NULL AS C_MASTER_SOURCE,
       EVT_HAS_Z,
       NULL AS C_MASTER_NOTES,
       NULL AS C_MASTER_SERVICE,
       NULL AS CER_CUSTOMER
FROM C_event
WHERE EVT_end_date >= NOW()

UNION ALL

SELECT 'WHISPER' AS C_MASTER_CHANGE_ID,
       WISP_SUMMARY,
       WISP_START_DATE,
       WISP_END_DATE,
       NULL AS C_MASTER_LEVEL,
       NULL AS C_MASTER_SOURCE,
       NULL AS EVT_HAS_Z,
       NULL AS C_MASTER_NOTES,
       NULL AS C_MASTER_SERVICE,
       NULL AS CER_CUSTOMER
FROM C_wispering
WHERE WISP_END_DATE >= NOW()
```

This is a little simplified version of my query because otherwhise it would have been hardly managable for a asking for help post.

Comment: What are your number of rows coming from the db approximately? What are your indexes like? on which fields and so on?

Comment: @Tikkes about 6000 rows approximately. I only have C_MASTER_ID and CER_ID indexed. I have been reluctant with indexes because i simply do not know alot about it. Are there any downsides to index more fields?

Comment: You should really consider reading up on indexes in that case. The SQL documentation is extensive on this and can be enormously helpful when dealing with more complex databases. Indexes can be extremely good when used correctly and enhance performance a ton. Of course, putting indexes on anything or everything has downsides which is why you should put indexes on fields often needed or often used in search queries, also combined indexes can be used to your advantage most of the time. [Documentation on indexes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175049.aspx)

Comment: @Tikkes thank you very much! Seems like I cannot bypass this subject any longer. Would you say the query looks okay otherwise?

Comment: Would believe so - not knowing the db of course - but why are you doing: `master.C_MASTER_START >= NOW()
  AND master.C_MASTER_START >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 21 DAY)`? Since your second check already states it should be **after** 21 days in the past, why then check first for `NOW()`?

Comment: @Tikkes Argh! That was a typo when I simplified the query for this post. It should be `master.C_MASTER_END >= NOW()` and `master.C_MASTER_START >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 21 DAY)` so that it catches active or future events not older than 21days ago. Thank you for the reply! :D

Comment: It's worth reading http://use-the-index-luke.com/ to get up to speed on indexing. Also, when you ask for query-performance help, it's vital to post the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE whatever` for each table involved in your query. Please [edit] your question if you need a more detailed answer than @GordonLInoff has offered.

Comment: @OllieJones thanks so much! I think i'll try the indexing and hope for the best. Thank you all for the help and the info regarding `SHOW CREATE TABLE` output (although that would have been quite extensive! I don't know if you helpful stackoverflow people would like that? :)).

Answer (score 2):

You should run each query separately, to determine which is causing the performance problems.  You can also look at "explain" to see the plans.

Off-hand, I can say that the first query would benefit from indexes on `c_master(C_MASTER_START, C_MASTER_ID)` and `c2customer(CER_ID, CER_CUSTOMER)`.

The second would benefit from an index on `C_event(EVT_end_date)`.  And the third:  `C_wispering(WISP_END_DATE)`.

Comment: Sidenote to this though, when putting an index on datetimes, it might be wise to consider not including miliseconds/seconds/minutes and aim for hours instead to reduce the load. More info about performance can also be found on [this stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17381875/how-to-improve-performance-for-datetime-filtering-in-sql-server)

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer!! Up until now i only have CER_ID and C_MASTER_ID indexed. I have been reluctant with indexes simply because I don't know a lot about it :/ - would there be any downsides to index more fields, any risks when indexing the fields you suggested or can I just index away? (I do have a daily write-process on the DB which so far wasn't touched when I indexed C_MASTER_ID and CER_ID but I'm scared it will slow down a lot if I index any more)

Comment: @tikkes With respect, a DATETIME index is certainly the best way to handle this sort of thing. The accepted answer at the link you provided contains some serious misinformation about the complexity of datetime indexing.

Comment: @OllieJones would you know if there's a risk of slowing down a big daily write operation significantly if i index datetime?

Comment: If you had 6 gigarows there might be, but probably not. With 6megarows, certainly not. With 6000 rows you won't even notice it. MySQL, and other RDMS systems, are built to handle very large volumes.

Comment: @OllieJones perfect information, thank you very much!