# SQL Server: Nonclustered Date Index

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to optimize performance of my Logs table by adding an nonclustered index on my LogDate (DateTime) column to improve performance since most of my queries will include a time frame (From Date - To Date). The Thread bellow recommends rounding to the closest hour.

[How to improve performance for datetime filtering in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17381875/how-to-improve-performance-for-datetime-filtering-in-sql-server)

I'm looking for an best practice example & advice of an index on a datetime column to improve performance.

Thanks in advance

Comment: That accepted answer is nonsense

Comment: That is off-topic for SO. And no one can give you guidance about indexes without knowing precisely the queries you use to access and manipulate your rows, the DDL of the tables involved,  and some idea of the content of your rows and its evolution over time. And there is no such thing as "best practice" with regard to indexes. Indexing is always very specific to the schema and usage.

Answer (score 1):

The referenced answer in your question is either wrong or missing some critical details. Adding an additional `datetime` column with a rounded value will not reduce the index size. The `datetime` data type is a fixed 8 bytes regardless of the value stored. To realize a reduced index size, one would need to use a different data type, such as `smalldatetime` (which is only 4 bytes with resolution of no more than one minute), and/or use data compression.

If queries most often specify a datetime range alone, the clustered index should be on datetime column. A common anti-pattern I see in the wild is an clustered identity column primary key, which is serves no purpose. Log tables are an exception to the general rule that tables should have a primary key since they are not relational.

You may also need non-clustered indexes on frequently specified additional columns if they are fairly selective but should do so sparingly as to avoid impacting insert performance. Consider using `datetime2` along with the maximum precision needed, possibly saving a byte or 2 per row. Also consider page compression for both the table and indexes. I've used this approach with multi-billion row log tables and realized excellent performance.

Comment: I've considered to place my clustered index on my datetime column, but  was worried about impacting insert performance. I'm sure if this approached worked with "Multi-billion" rows, I was worried about nothing. Thanks for the explanation and great answer.

Comment: @Ross, the scenario I mentioned inserted data using SqlBulkCopy. Incremental CI keys with singleton inserts and very high transaction rates (several thousand/sec) may reduce constraint throughput depending on your server/storage system. It shouldn't be difficult to throw together a perf test to validate the best approach for your workload and environment.