# Get all records by month in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to pull records from a view that shows records for the next 90 days. I need a way to pull those records out by month only. I need that because not all months contain 30 days. Here is an example that shows records from today, and for the next 30 days.

```
select * 
from [dbo].[vPolicy_Renewal_90DayLookUp] AS PRD 
where PRD.ExpDate BETWEEN GETDATE() AND DATEADD(DD, 30, GETDATE()) 
order by PRD.ExpDate
```

This gets all records from today and the next 30 days but, I want a way to capture ALL records for the month. Since it's November, the previous 5 days and the rest of the month.

Comment: What's the database engine? Oracle, DB2, PostgreSQL, etc.

Comment: You stated three different requirements here. What are you trying to retrieve? The records for the next three months?

Comment: @TheImpaler Gotta be either SQL Server (most likely) or Access.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yeah, looks like SAP ASE too.

Comment: @The Impaler. The engine is SQL

Comment: SQL is not an engine

Comment: @swapmeet_Lou SQL is language that is used by many database engines; it's not a database.

Comment: @ Mureinik  I want to be able to display the records on a month by month basis based on the next 90 days. Based on it being November, I would want November, December, and January. Etc.

Comment: @The Impaler.. alright.. for ignorance sakes.. I don't know what you mean by engine. I am retrieving this data using SQL language on a SQL server. Using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 17. I'm not sure what else you need

Comment: Then SQL Server is your engine/DBMS

Comment: Unsure of why the question got a down vote. I've searched up and down for the answer but, nothing that answers the question I have asked. Please advise how to fix

Comment: Have you tried, `WHERE DATEPART(MONTH,PRD.ExpDate) = 11`

Comment: @JonTout I hadn't tried that. Two things. I just did and the query won't execute. I have to cancel it. Other part is I didn't want to create 12 separate views. I wanted one query that would dynamically cover all months as they progress through the year

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "query won't execute", but changing my answer to `WHERE DATEPART(MONTH,PRD.ExpDate) = DATEPART(MONTH,GetDate()) ` will return all queries for the current month.

Comment: @JonTout What I mean by that is, when execute the query with the line of code you provided. SQL remains in the Executing query mode (with the spinning wheel) and never recovers. It never finishes or returns any rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a query for the current month:

```
SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[vPolicy_Renewal_90DayLookUp] AS PRD
WHERE
    PRD.ExpDate >= DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, @mydate), 0) AND
    PRD.ExpDate < DATEADD(mm, 1, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, @mydate), 0));
```

For the second month, use this `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE
    PRD.ExpDate >= DATEADD(mm, 1, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, @mydate), 0)) AND
    PRD.ExpDate < DATEADD(mm, 2, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, @mydate), 0));
```

And continue this way for the third and subsequent months.  If you want just a single query for the current and next two months, then use this:

```
SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[vPolicy_Renewal_90DayLookUp] AS PRD
WHERE
    PRD.ExpDate >= DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, @mydate), 0) AND
    PRD.ExpDate < DATEADD(mm, 3, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, @mydate), 0))
ORDER BY
    PRD.ExpDate;
```

You should see each of the three months, in separate blocks, from earliest record to latest record.

Comment: @swapmeet_Lou Reload your page, as I've edited my answer since what you are seeing.  My query _does_ pull the next 90 days.

Comment: So do you want a column stating the month?  Do you just want the record ordered some way?  I can't read your mind.

Comment: Confusing.  Do you want _one_ query/view, or _multiple_ queries/views?

Comment: Let me get this straight: the date is Nov 5. You need to see Nov 1 to Nov 30. Your starting data source is a view showing  the next 90 days (Nov 5 to Feb 3-ish). **There's nothing you can do that will get those first 4 days.** The period from Nov 1 to Nov 4 isn't gonna happen. _They're not part of your source data._ You either need to use a different data source, or change the view you're using as the source to include that data.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Let me get this straight.  It _is_ permissible to drop random comments under someone's question which have nothing to directly do with that person's question?  300K points?  Seriously?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Relex, this is addressed at swapmeet, not you, because the "not previous" part of his first comment on this answer raises concerns he's expecting data he'll never get to see.

Comment: We are going in circles here.  Do you want _one_ query, perhaps with a month column so you may distinguish?  Or do you want _separate_ queries, one for each of the current and next two months?

Comment: @swapmeet_Lou Can you remove all your comments?  They don't add much to the answer, and it looks ugly.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Throwing this out as an answer, rather than a comment - this should return all rows for a given month, based on each day of "this month"

```
SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[vPolicy_Renewal_90DayLookUp] AS PRD
WHERE 
    DATEPART(MONTH,PRD.ExpDate) = DATEPART(MONTH,GetDate())
    AND DATEPART(YEAR, PRD.ExpDate) = DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE())
```

**Add:** 
You may need an index on your ExpDate field, as per [How to improve performance for datetime filtering in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17381875/how-to-improve-performance-for-datetime-filtering-in-sql-server)

Comment: Hmm maybe the year is important too?

Comment: I would have thought so.

Comment: I edited the above query and logic for the year as well.  You need that or else it would include data from other years.  ex. 11/2018, 11/2017, 11/2016 etc...

Comment: I thank you for the answer. Unfortunately, this for one reason or another does not seem to work. I've literally copied the code and it simply won't execute.

Answer (score 0):

@Tim Biegeleisen I found a few things with your answer.  I tried using the SQL month() function but, due to earlier conversion in the DB it would never execute. That answers why @JonTout answer would not work correctly. I was able to accomplish what I wanted to by doing it this way.

```
DECLARE @mydate DATE, @myEndDate DATE;
SET @mydate = '12/01/2018';
SET @myEndDate = '12/31/2018';
SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[vPolicy_Renewal_90DayLookUp] AS PRD
WHERE  PRD.ExpDate >= DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, @mydate), 0) AND
PRD.ExpDate < DATEADD(mm, 1, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, @myEndDate), 0))

order by ExpDate
```

I am grateful for your help @Tim Biegeleisen. I found another solution to the problem I was having. This will display all records in the current month and allow me make a stored procedure for a user to choose what month they want for the next 90 days.

```
DECLARE @Diff Int
Set @Diff = 0

SELECT PRD.Client, PRD.ExpDate
FROM [dbo].[vPolicy_Renewal_90DayLookUp] AS PRD

where (Year(ExpDate) = YEAR(getdate()))  
AND DATENAME(month, ExpDate) = DATENAME(MONTH, (Dateadd(Month, @Diff,GETDATE())))

order by ExpDate asc
```

I could do the same without the year() but, it works for now. I found this way to make a bit more sense to me.