# SQL order by in two steps

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, sql-order-by, query-optimization

I have a big table with two datetime columns.

**[Timestamp]** and **[TimestampRounded]**

The **[Timestamp]** column has the full timestamp including milliseconds and the table has no index for this column.

The **[TimestampRounded]** column has the timestamp but milliseconds, seconds, and minutes truncated (set to 0). The table has a clustered index for this column. That is, the table is effectively stored in the order of this column. Typically the newest row is on the top of the table. The index was created like this:

```
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX cidx_time ON [dbo].[MyTable] ([TimestampRounded] DESC)
```

Now, I want to retrieve some data leveraging my clustered index so I do the following select, my table has around 5 million rows.

Query 1:

```
SELECT TOP(100) * FROM [dbo].[MyTable] ORDER BY [TimestampRounded] DESC
```

This query returns immediately (less than 1 second). But the 100 returned rows are not ordered with respect to milliseconds, only by hour.

Then I learned if I also want to order by a second column I do:

Query 2:

```
SELECT TOP(100) * FROM [dbo].[MyTable] ORDER BY [TimestampRounded] DESC, [Timestamp] DESC
```

This query is very slow and takes around 23 seconds to return the 100 rows.

My immediate solution was to use the first query and then just order those returned 100 rows in my client frontend code. But I experienced some problem that I missed rows that should have returned so I would like to understand how I can fix/rewrite query 2 to return those 100 sorted rows as expected, and by reasonable logic should also take less than 1 second. Since the table is already stored by hour (clustered index) I do not understand why it should take longer.

Comment: How many rows are *tied* on the same top value(s) for `TimestampRounded`?

Comment: Several thousand rows can be tied to the TimestampRounded value. That is every row that occurred during that hour

Comment: Exactly - so your first query is "give me *any* 100 of the rows that share the same hour value" - whereas your second query is "give me exactly the 100 rows that are latest" - the second takes more time.

Comment: So what would be reasonable to get the correct data? Use [Timestamp] for the clustered index? As far as I know that is not optimal due to the index will be unreasonable especially due to milliseconds and seconds in the timestamp

Comment: I used the answer for this question as reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17381875/how-to-improve-performance-for-datetime-filtering-in-sql-server

Comment: So now you have to understand that it's a *trade-off*. You may pay some additional cost during insert vs being able to retrieve the data efficiently here - I've never had any particular issues including datetime columns in clustered indexes, but if you have *measurable* performance issues, now you've got to decide which is more important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be oversimplifying, but why not simply create an index on the column that stores the entire timestamp?

```
CREATE INDEX cidx_time2 ON [dbo].[MyTable] ([Timestamp] DESC)
```

Then, you can just do:

```
SELECT TOP(100) * FROM [dbo].[MyTable] ORDER BY [[Timestamp] DESC
```

Or, if you need to two timestamps in the `order by` clause for some reason, then you want an index on both columns:

```
CREATE INDEX cidx_time3 ON [dbo].[MyTable] ([TimestampRounded] DESC, [Timestamp] DESC);
```

Then you can run your original query:

```
SELECT TOP(100) * FROM [dbo].[MyTable] ORDER BY [TimestampRounded] DESC, [Timestamp] DESC
```

Comment: I learned that the INSERT's would be very tedious if my clustered index holds milliseconds, seconds and minutes. Thats why I use the Rounded column in first place

Comment: See the answer for this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17381875/how-to-improve-performance-for-datetime-filtering-in-sql-server

Comment: No that's just wrong. Either way it's a 64 bit value to sort on, it will have the same performance. Certainly adding *another* column is going to make it better

Comment: What is wrong? Are you saying I should just remove the Rounded column and use clustered index on [Timestamp]?

Comment: @Smith5727: if you want to speed up the query that sorts on the entire timestamp, then I think you need an index on the entire timestamp. If the storage impact matters to you (as suggested in the answer you linked), then you might want to monitor that when you create the index.

Comment: @Smith5727 the accepted answer you linked is best ignored - the phrase `the index has to account for every place within the datetime. This becomes very large spatially and bulky.`  would indicate to me that the author probably has no idea how indexes work

Comment: Thanks MartinSmith and Charlieface . Although @Charlieface, what do you mean by adding another column would make it better? I am thinking now to create the index like you did (cidx_time3) would be the most efficient way. Then I could fine query but also query fast on whole dates. But is there actually any performance gain or hit between cidx_time2 and cidx_time3?

Comment: Just use the original column

Answer (score 1):

Specify `WITH TIES` so sqlserver will return you [upto] "several thousand" rows that have all the same rounded timestamp value, then order those several thousand by the precise time stamp to get your truly most recent 100; quicker to sort thousands than millions