# Heroku Postgres Performance

Tags: sql, postgresql, heroku

On large tables, getting the rows by "updated_at > 1 minutes ago" is very slow (it's a non-indexed date column).

Does upgrading Heroku Postgres to a higher tier make this kind of queries faster? I'm using Standard 2 at the moment.

Context: I'm using https://www.stitchdata.com to replicate my Postgres to Redshift, and the replication takes ≈10 minutes because of these slow queries. Heroku Postgres doesn't support "Log-based Incremental Replication".

Comment: Why don't you create an index?

Comment: I'm considering it :)

Would you round the date to the hour as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30678751/10671305?

Thanks!

Comment: "On large tables, getting the rows by "updated_at > 1 minutes ago" is very slow (it's a non-indexed date column)"—yep, the lack of index is almost certainly the problem, not the underlying database tier. Index first. This site is ugly, but has good content: https://use-the-index-luke.com/