# How to get date format (dd-MMM-yy HH:mm:ss) in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to convert `getdate()` to this format (`10-Feb-15 18:25:57`) in SQL Server.

```
select getdate()
```

gets me

```
2015-02-10 18:25:37.567
```

but I want date in `10-Feb-15 18:25:37` format.

How to covert this date format into my required format?

I am new to SQL Server.

Thanks ....

Comment: possible duplicate of [Omitting the Milliseconds in a Date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246655/omitting-the-milliseconds-in-a-date)

Comment: It's almost always better to keep this data in `DateTime` variables (which don't *have* formats) throughout the database and only convert it into a string (and apply formatting) when presenting the data to the user - usually, there's a more appropriate layer (reporting tools or another language) where such formatting concerns are easily dealt with, rather than trying to do it in T-SQL inside the database.

Answer (score 4):

It's not exactly that, but closest to that is:

```
select convert(varchar, getdate(), 113)

10 Feb 2015 15:00:30:513
```

To get without milliseconds you can shorten the string:

```
select convert(varchar(20), getdate(), 113)
```

You can find the formats here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928%28v=sql.100%29.aspx

If you really need that exact format, I think you'll have to work with datepart / datename.

Answer (score 4):

This will get you the exact format:

```
SELECT 
  STUFF(STUFF(CONVERT(char(20), getdate(), 113),3,1, '-'),7,1,'-')
```

Answer (score 2):

The date types do not have any format, they are binary types. Formats apply only when you want to convert a date value to a string.

In SQL Server 2012+ you can use the [FORMAT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx) function to format a date to any of the standard format strings supported by .NET, or a custom format string, eg:

```
DECLARE @d DATETIME = GETDATE();
SELECT FORMAT( @d, 'dd-MMM-yy HH:mm:ss', 'en-US' ) 
------------------
10-Feb-15 15:35:55
```

In previous versions of SQL Server you are limited to using a few predefined formats using [CONVERT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928%28v=sql.100%29.aspx), or constructing the final string by concatenating the date part values.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(11),SYSDATETIME(),13),' ','-')+' '+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), SYSDATETIME(), 8)
```

Answer (score 0):

we can convert date into many formats 

SELECT convert(NVARCHAR, getdate(), 106) 

This may help you  [Click](https://anubhavg.wordpress.com/2009/06/11/how-to-format-datetime-date-in-sql-server-2005/)

Answer (score 0):

In your case there is no regular datetime format that fits your need. You will have to format date and time separately, and also replace spaces with dashes.

The following will generate a datetime in your requested format:

```
select replace(convert(varchar(9), getdate(), 6), ' ', '-')
       + ' ' + convert(varchar(8), getdate(), 8)
```

Result:

```
10-Feb-15 14:08:54
```

MSDN documentation on formatting datetime: [CAST and CONVERT (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)